# Find element dict based on elements of a list

Tags: ruby

I have a dict similar to:

```
{"services"=>["foo", "bar", "test"], "foo_limit_max"=>2, "test_limit_min"=>6}
```

I want to extract from the list of `services` all of those services that have a key following `servicename_limit_*`

I tried the following `dict['services'].select { |x| dict.key?(/#{x}_limit_*/)}` but it's not returning anything.

Expected output would be `['foo', 'test']`

Comment: Have an inner loop that will iterate keys of the hash and match each key against your regex (or do a simpler check, like `start_with?`)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I use `grep` whenever possible only for its name :) (also it’s faster than an iteration, but that’s not as important as the name.)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: performance claim needs to be backed by hard numbers :) I have a feeling that string prefix is faster than regex-powered grep. The latter does look nicer, of course.

Comment: In Ruby we don't call them a dictionary, we call them a hash. People will still understand what you mean, but for example the class name is [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html).

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: [10x difference](https://pastebin.com/nSb1ABP4), this is hard to throw away :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ok, ok, you’ve got me. I love how you optimized yours to avoid string interpolation unless strictly necessary to get to 10× :)))

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: without the opto it's _only_ 8x ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input['services'].reject do |x|
  input.keys.grep(/\A#{x}_limit_/).empty?
end
#⇒ ["foo", "test"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go about it like this

```
dict['services'] & dict.keys.flat_map {|k| k.scan(/\w+(?=_limit_)/)}
```

Here we use `Array#&` (intersection) between the `dict['services']` and the keys that match the given pattern.

```
dict.keys.flat_map {|k| k.scan(/\w+(?=_limit_)/)}
#=> ["foo", "test"]
```

Another as suggested by [@SergioTulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480277/find-element-dict-based-on-elements-of-a-list/57480713#comment101432274_57480277) (which is far more performant) is

```
dict['services'].select {|s| dict.any? {|k,_| k.start_with?(s)}}
```

[Benchmarks Provided By @SergioTulentsev](https://pastebin.com/UH3vEBTH)

```
# >> Warming up --------------------------------------
# >>               sergio    54.608k i/100ms
# >>              aleksei     6.257k i/100ms
# >>                 cary    40.951k i/100ms
# >>        engineersmnky    16.093k i/100ms
# >> Calculating -------------------------------------
# >>               sergio    663.692k (± 3.5%) i/s -      3.331M in   5.025472s
# >>              aleksei     64.006k (± 2.9%) i/s -    325.364k in   5.087717s
# >>                 cary    472.838k (± 3.1%) i/s -      2.375M in   5.028133s
# >>        engineersmnky    167.907k (± 2.0%) i/s -    852.929k in   5.081762s
# >>
# >> Comparison:
# >>               sergio:   663691.8 i/s
# >>                 cary:   472838.2 i/s - 1.40x  slower
# >>        engineersmnky:   167906.6 i/s - 3.95x  slower
# >>              aleksei:    64005.5 i/s - 10.37x  slower
# >>
```

Comment: "more performant" is an understatement :) https://pastebin.com/UH3vEBTH

Comment: Could you rerun the benchmarks until my solution is fastest?

Comment: @CarySwoveland of course. *Change your solution* :)

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {"services"=>["foo", "bar", "test"], "foo_limit_max"=>2, "test_limit_min"=>6}
```

```
h["services"] & h.keys.map { |k| k[/.+?(?=_limit_)/] }
  #=> ["foo", "test"]
```

Note:

```
h.keys.map { |k| k[/.+?(?=_limit_)/] }
  #=> [nil, "foo", "test"]
```

See [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-26), which includes the sentence, "The order is preserved from the original array.".

Comment: What I meant was in this case there would be no difference between `.+?` and `.*` unless you are assuming there is a service of `""` that should be excluded for some reason

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes. I was just worried that a key might be changed to `"foo_limit_limit_max"` sometime in future. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ (I shouldn't have deleted my first comment as I mashed the context.)

Comment: Well now at least I understand your thought process although who knows maybe `foo_limit` is a valid service. Either way it is better than `flat_map {...scan}` (what idiot thought that was a good idea :))